# Update varbinary(MAX) column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, hex, varbinary

I am trying to update a varbinary(MAX) column, it actually stores saved data of a Word file that an user uploaded from a website.

What happened was an user uploaded a wrong file so I need to update the column to reflect a correct file.

What I did was that in a testing machine I uploaded the correct file so it was saved to the database and I can see and copy the "varbinary(MAX) value" and use it to replace the wrong one

The value looks like: 0x504B03041400060008000........FBB9

I tried a straight forward UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE my_table Set datafile =  0x504B03041400060008000........FBB9
```

It says 1 row(s) affected, but that file can't be open after downloaded from the font-end web, I notice that saved value is `0x0504B03041400060008000........FBB` (1 more extra **0** after 0x and the **9** at the end disappeared)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra 0 is being added because the entire value you are setting it to is odd. SQL Server will pad it with an extra 0 to make it even.

```
declare @varmax varbinary(max) 
set @varmax = 0x1234567         --odd
select @varmax                  --returns 0x01234567 with the padded 0

set @varmax = 0x12345678        --even
select @varmax                  --returns 0x12345678
```

Your 9 is being dropped because you are entering an odd number of bytes that fills the max value. So, a 0 is inserted but this overflows the max number of bytes and thus is also truncated it seems. I was able to replicate your error... but don't know a way around it yet.

Here is the value i used for your test. Ignore the results... but you can copy them into your own SSMS and see the correct output.

http://rextester.com/LMGQ8686

Comment: same problem when I used your query above with my value. Here is the same problem but I dont understand the solution, can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913283

Comment: can you paste your value? If not, does it also happen when you SET ANSI_PADDING OFF

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding added an edit. Haven't figured out how to prevent it, but figured out WHY